# JavaScript: Why don't <input type="image"> elements appear in document.forms.elements?

Tags: javascript, collections

I read the other day on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)  that the `document.forms[x].element` collection will not contain input elements of type="image". Why not? I checked this out on Firefox 50.1.0, and sure enough, I could not find the `input type="image"` in `document.forms.elements`.

I am not stuck or anything. I am just wondering why this is (other than the presence of an `src=""` attribute and the image it displays).

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) states:

> The HTMLFormElement.elements property returns an
>   HTMLFormControlsCollection (HTML 4 HTMLCollection) of all the form
>   controls contained in the FORM element, with the exception of input
>   elements which have a type attribute of image.

The [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-elements) says:

> The elements IDL attribute must return an HTMLFormControlsCollection
>   rooted at the form element, whose filter matches listed elements whose
>   form owner is the form element, with the exception of input elements
>   whose type attribute is in the Image Button state, which must, for
>   historical reasons, be excluded from this particular collection.

The [World Wide Web Consortium](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/image) says:

> The image button state represents either an image from which a user
>   can select a coordinate and submit the form, or alternatively a button
>   from which the user can submit the form. The element is a button,
>   specifically a submit button.

Comment: Perhaps you should follow the links provided to [*the specifications*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-elements) (which are more authoritative than MDN): "*…with the exception of input elements whose type attribute is in the Image Button state, which must, for historical reasons, be excluded from this particular collection.*"

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-elements says it's "*for historical reasons*". Without further explanation, that would probably mean they have no good reason but something breaks when they don't keep it backwards-compatible.

Comment: @Berg—the very much earlier [*DOM 2 spec*](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) (2003) doesn't have this restriction, so the history is very long. Is this an example of the "living specification" stating what browsers do rather than what they *should* do?

Comment: @RobG Yes, it appears to be more important that all browsers expose the same bug than to fix the bug. Cross-browser compatibility above everything else!

Comment: I think this type of DOM access is generally considered archaic, so there's little incentive to fix it. They simply documented how browsers behave, and left it at that.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge And the "pure JavaScript enthusiast" has to realize that these mechanisms still work the way they did 20 years ago. You're not just an enthusiast, you're an archeologist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked a number of resources regarding the matter and specifically found this websites which dates back to July 15th, 1999:

http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/trysub.html

The input element with type=image specifically served as an image map and contained attributes and features no other HTMLFormElement was or is capable of. I remember it being used for maps and other graphics where users would pick a specific spot on the map, the coordinates being transferred back to the server and its cgi application which would then serve content based on the coordinates clicked. From my opinion it is one of the few archaic remains in modern browser and can be considered a zombie feature.

In Mozilla's Bugzilla there can also be issues found that are reporting unusual behavior of this element that neither conforms with images nor with input elements:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110595

I am not able to find the Netscape Navigator source code from 1998 quickly and also don't think that there would be any useful comments on this in it. I am pretty well damn sure that this decision was made as the IMAGE-input element is so weird, strange and different to the others that it is just not worth the specification, design and development effort to change its behavior in any direction. Implementing it as a FORM-element in the JavaScript Core and the DOM was just not worth it.

Everything I have found leads to this conclusion, but to have substantial evidence we need to find the guy that made the decision and that made the first implementation that led to this specification decision. It is, of course, exciting from a historic perspective.

Comment: In summary, the original full intention of an input type="image" was not simply to create a decorative submit button, and therefore there was no need to mandate a `value` attribute in early HTML specifications. Thus, if there was no mandatory value attribute, and the emphasis was on coordinates and image maps, it was determined that `type="image"` input buttons were more like images (etc ...) then the other true, scalar input types. No mandatory value attribute, no mandatory presence in document.forms[x].elements.

Comment: Thank you for your honest efforts.